# Check if the list contains at lease one non null object

Tags: java, list, if-statement, collections

Is there any method that will check if the List is not empty and has one object which is not null?

Is there any better alternative for the following code

```
if( !list.isEmpty() && list.get(0) != null){
    ...
}
```

Please let me know if this piece of code can be improved in any way.

Comment: I don't think you need the second part '&& list.get(0) != null' as that is already taken care of by the isEmpty() call. Moreover list.get(0) could by null while list.get(1) is not null so it doesn't add value based on your criteria.

Comment: @mba12 I only care of the first object is not null.

Comment: If that's the case you should edit your question to reflect the criteria that only the first object is not null.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 9):

I guess you could try with java 8

```
if (list.stream().anyMatch(e -> e != null)) {... }
```

Comment: Or `anyMatch(Objects::nonNull)`

Comment: @tobias_k this is the best answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work. What happens if the `null` element is the second or the third?

A simple way is to use the method [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)):

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

If you need to check if it exists exactly one NOT null element here is the code you need to write:

```
int countNull = 0;
for (Object obj : list) {
    if (obj == null) {
        countNull++;
    }
}
if (countNull == list.size() - 1) {
    // Contains exactly one not null element
}
```

Comment: I want to check if only one object exists which is non null.

Comment: Nope, OP wants to check whether there is _at least_ one _non_ null element.

Comment: @codeMan What do you mean? Do you want to check whether there is _exactly_ one non-null element? In this case, please update your question title.

Comment: @codeMan thanks. I edited my answer (the second part) to show how to see if the list contains exactly one not null element.

Comment: List.contains also may throw an NPE (depending on the list implementation), so it's actually potentially problematic to call contains(null).
Even more so ever since List.of(..) creates one of those List implementations actually throwing said NPE.